# pub serve to non-root directory

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Is it possible to run `pub serve` during dev and have the application available on `localhost:8888/application` instead of `localhost:8888` ?

I don't see any flags that I can specify on pub itself, so was wondering if there's some kind of transformer I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Maybe adding a symlink

```
my_project/web/application
```

that points to

```
my_project/web
```

allows you to do what you want.

Another option is to use  a proxy that forwards

```
http://localhost:8888/application
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Using a proxy is also the recommended solution when you need to use a 3rd-party server during development where requests for Dart resources are forwarded to `pub serve` and everything else to the 3rd-party server.

Comment: I'm currently using NGINX which rewrites the URLs in production (app had to move from `/` to `/application`), which means I have different URLs in dev and production. I'll experiment a bit with simlink and proxies, thanks Gunter!

Comment: Symlinks in dev just causes it to never finish serving, almost like it's going into an infinite loop. Had to setup an NGINX proxy locally on dev to forward everything and then use that same config in prod. It now means that if I want to dev against it, I need to have NGINX running as well; not great,  but it gets the job done.